# Forwarding a folder in syslog-ng?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, syslog, syslog-ng

I'm trying to forward `realtime_01-08-15.log` to `192.168.1.132` using syslog-ng. I think I know how to forward traffic from a file but what if the file changes name daily?

Source on Jan 8th 2015:
`realtime_01-08-15.log`

Source on Jan 9th 2015:
`realtime_01-09-15.log`

Do I have to make the source a folder and put the log file in there or is there a way for variable source input? Any help would be appreciated and an extra info can be provided if needed.

Answer (score 0):

at the moment, only the commercial version of syslog-ng can use wildcards in filenames (that would solve the problem), but this feature is not yet available in the open source version.

As a workaround, you could create a cron job that exports the name of the file as an environment variable, use that variable in the filename of your syslog-ng source, and reload syslog-ng once a day.

For details, see
http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.6-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.6-guide-admin/html/config-global-variables.html

HTH,

Regards,

Robert Fekete

Comment: Hmm I have no problem scripting but I don't want to finagle around on a production server. Thanks though!